# What is optimal distance between inverse of convolution operator?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, global-optimization

I am looking for a measure to find the optimal distance measure between inverse of an convolution operator $A$ and say another convolution operator $B$. I want my measure to be sharp that mean when $B$ is correct inverse of $A$ then measure reach an extreme value and for any other matrix the measure is far off the extreme value. Is there any wok on such measure? Any reference or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: It cab be minimum norm or some other measure of sharpness. My interest is in some measure of sharpness, which I am not sure.